# Are all transcendental numbers theoretically accessible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I apologize if the title (and the body) of this question is worded incorrectly, but I have no real experience in (transcendental) number theory, so it's probably the best I can do.

I've been thinking about irrational numbers recently, and a lot of my questions seem to come down to this: can we, in principle, *show* every transcendental number in some way?

Premise for the relevance of the question: Transcendentals must be *shown* rather than stated plainly, as can be done with (irrational) algebraic numbers. Perhaps I am wrong when I say this (please tell me if I am), but all definitions of π ultimately come down the ratio of a circle's circumference to it's diameter, and *e* must also be defined it terms of its *use* in a very specific, or rather, unique function. This is, more or less, what I mean by *showing*: that transcendental numbers must be given by their *use* in some definite structure ("structure" is here being used very broadly... again, I don't really have the proper mathematical vocabulary yet).

Now let me go back to my original question: can we always think of a context to fit **any given** transcendental number? Not necessarily a geometric construction, but some situation that provides a unique value that is a transcendental number.

Finally, links to any books, journal articles, etc., that may relate to or include this topic would be much appreciated.

I hope this made sense.

Comment: There are only countable infinitely many ways of *showing a number* (if I understood you correctly). This means that most of the reals cannot be shown. All the algebraic numbers obviously can, so it does look like transcendentals are a bit left out. Mind you, I'm fairly sure this has been asked and answered here before. As something called *computable numbers* or some such.

Comment: Just a comment: $\pi$ is usually defined in relation to a circle, but there are also ways to define it in relation to the prime numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only a countable number of "[definable real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number)", transcendental or otherwise, so if your notion of "showing" a number falls within the confines of definable, then the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. I'm a little unclear about the difference between "definable" and "computable," (except that computables are a subset of definables, which is actually the main problem for me) but I'm sure I'll be able find that distinction somewhere. Also: is my description of transcendentals roughly accurate? I know it isn't in any formal sense, but is it true that the only way to "grasp" a transcendental is to find it in some kind of relation? Even a "computable" number doesn't seem to allow one to know that number, in the sense that one can π and √2.

Comment: I didn't see you give any description of transcendental numbers... You just seemed to be talking about "pinning down" a number with some definition, geometric or otherwise.

Comment: And computable means there is a computer program that can compute the number to arbitrary precision. Definable is a broader term which encompasses all numbers which can be uniquely determined by some conditions in the language of set theory.